"see with right/left eye" OR "see out of right/left eye?

He has not been able to see out of his right eye for the past four months, and his left eye is "not the greatest" BBC - Elton john

see out of his right eye caught my attention, because I have previously never seen it being used this way. I have seen see with right eye or left eye.
So, I wonder if both are commonly used?

Did you search for "see out of his right eye" Click on the link Books

*and climbing to his feet, unable to see out of his right eye. What he remembered best was the pain , the excruciating pain in his eye and the right side of his head.*

@Mari-LouA, I did a search for both "see out of his right eye" and "see with his right eye". They both bring results.

If you accept "look out of a window" is easily understood and grammatical, you'll see (pun unintended) why a sensory verb such as view, see, watch or observe  + out of + something is acceptable. EDIT So why are you asking if both forms are right? What makes you doubt the validity of the former?

Why are you questioning the BBC's usage? What is your reason?

@Lambie, I am not questioning. I just want to make sure whether "see with an eye" or "see out of an eye" are both commonly used, because I have never seen "see out of an eye" although I have been learning english for years. I want to make sure whether or not it might be a special usage, non-standard, regional, etc.

Ok, so in these contexts, I would put it in google, one, then the other and check the resulting sites. Anyway, see out of a left or right eye is the same as: see with a left or right eye.

In fact, window comes from two Norse words that mean "wind" and "eye", vindauga.

What's odd, is that people say "I can hear only out of one ear".

It's extremely common, perhaps because it's slightly less formal. I typically prefer it, actually.

I can't see out of my right eye.

is what I would say versus:

I can't see with my right eye.



I can't see out of my right eye.
I can't see with my right eye.

They both mean the same thing.
